# #Error when calculating two different times when one is null

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

Created a simple time sheet, in MS Access, to calculate pay.  However, unless there is an end time [TimeEnd] my form displays #error in the calculated field. I would like it just to stay blank if the it cannot calulate the time. Below is the sql statement.

```
TimeDurationAsDate([TimeLog].[TimeStart],[TimeLog].[TimeEnd]) AS TimeWorked
```

Thank You

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, ms-access...?

Comment: That is not an SQL statement, it is just a single expression to calculate a value. Could handle Null with Nz() or IIf() with IsNull() or Is Null to provide an alternate value. Or IIf() conditional to not even do calc when field Is Null. Nothing extraordinary here.

Answer (score 0):

Your secret *TimeDurationAsDate* function should be modified to handle that, but this will do:

```
CVDate([TimeLog].[TimeStart]-[TimeLog].[TimeEnd]) AS TimeWorked
```

It will return *Null* when *TimeEnd* is *Null*. Then apply to *TimeWorked* the format you prefer.